# Specific nginx redirect remove get params and add new

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I have problem with specific redirect
My url is
http://example.com/test/some_file.jpg?refferer=mobile
And this must redirect to
http://example.com/parser.php?q=some_file.jpg

Normal redirect(without get params) i i've done by

```
rewrite test/(.*) /parser.php?q=$1 last;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
location ~ ^/test/(.*)$ {
    if ($arg_referrer = mobile) {
        return 301 http://example.com/parser.php?q=$1;
    }
    # else ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not redirect, rewrite to
but without elements after ?

When i try somethink like you do, finally link be http://example.com/parser.php?q=some_file.jpg&referrer=mobile

Comment: then something like rewrite ^.*$ /parser.php?q=$1 last; instead of return 301, play with it, I guess $arg_referrer is what you needed to know about to solve your problem

Comment: Sorry, didn't get the point before you edited your comment. Yes, just add a "?" sign at the end, as Alexey Ten suggested

Answer (score 0):

http://nginx.org/r/rewrite

> If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended.

So answer is really simple:

```
rewrite test/(.*) /parser.php?q=$1? last;
```